# Try to connect login with php and mysql

Tags: html, http-status-code-404

I am trying to build a login form php and mysql i write the code.

But when i click login it a 404 page.

I create tables email VARCHAR 255 and password VARCHAR 255.

index.php

```
<?php

// Database connection
$servername = "localhost:3306";
$username = "root@";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";
// Establish a database connection
$conn = new mysqli("localhost:3306", "root@", "", "");

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Process form submission
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = password_hash($_POST["password"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    // Insert user data into the database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO register (email, password) VALUES ('$email', '$password')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Registration successful!";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}

// Close the database connection
$conn->close();
?>
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="register.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/logo_main.png" type="image/png" />
    <title>Techtack-Technologies | Portl register</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="RegisterContainer">
      <p>Techtack-Technologies | Portal Register</p>
    </div>
    <form action="register.php" id="registrationForm">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required />

      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required />

      <button type="submit" value="Register">Register</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I try to move the index.php file outside of the folder where i create the login page the folder is /portal/ so put it outside.

otherwise i try to search google and youtube.

Comment: add the datatse to your connrction string or send as first cpmand `USE databasename`

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: my database connection info.

Comment: see https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.construct.php  all connnection stidn have included a start  database

Comment: 404 error indicates that the requested url was not found. It does not indicate any problem with php or mysql. However, I must note that your login code suffers from lot of problems and after fixing the 404 issue you will still encounter lots of other issues.

Comment: Hello,  Is there a documentation a can i use to fix my code. Thank you

Comment: What is that mean when i click register and it download the .php file.